# Syntax error: unexpected token < in jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to run the test using jest using typescript preprocessor and i am getting following error

```
var component = react_test_renderer_1["default"].create(<jumbotron_1["default"] />);
                                                        ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

the following is tsconfig.json https://gist.github.com/fanofbits/cb2179c6d21ae6162319d7aa0500e483 thanks for help

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have set up babel-jest or your own preprocessor correctly. Please see the documentation but this doesn't seem like a bug in jest.

Comment: i have set up my preprocessor correctly you can see it here https://gist.github.com/fanofbits/cb2179c6d21ae6162319d7aa0500e483 i have added preprocessor.js

Answer (score 0):

> it using typescript preprocessor

Instead of using your own preprocessor which clearly has a bug that we need to find, just use `ts-jest` which works : https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest

Comment: i dont want to use it can you tell me what is bug